# DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that sends a message and gives you a role. The bot has the highest role, has Manage Roles permission and is trying to add the role to a normal guild member with the lowest role. I get this error every time I execute the command. I also reviewed this page https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#missing-permissions and checked everything but I keep getting the error.

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\perli\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Also, this is my code:

```js
if (command === 'participo') {
 const author = message.author;

 message.reply(
  `te has inscrito correctamente al torneo\nRecuerda unirte a este canal para participar https://discord.gg/4jue4uZ`
 );

 client.channels.cache
  .get('754701028888281168')
  .send(`<@${author.id}> se ha inscrito al torneo`);

 const role = message.guild.roles.cache.array(
  (role) => role.id === '754748890300940348'
 );
 message.member.roles
  .add(role)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the error already says `Missing Permissions` that means that your bot doesn't have permissions to give users a role that's above him or doesn't have the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission at all. If you want your bot to succeed giving out roles, make sure the role stack is something from this:

```
- UnreachableRole
- Bot Role
- Role 1
- Role 2
....
- Role 10
```

To this:

```
- Bot Role
- UnreachableRole
- Role 1
- Role 2
....
- Role 10
```

The `UnreachableRole` cannot be reached by bots as it got a higher position. To solve this, move the bot role to a position higher of the role you want to give.

Also make sure your bot has `MANAGE_ROLES` permissions.

Comment: He said the bot has the highest role

Comment: OMG, this has to be the 1 vote on the add role errors. I HAVE BEEN WORKING WITH DISCORD FOR AGES, had no idea that the roles had priority that I can drag one above the other. OMG. I've been breaking my head on this for a week! the role had admin privileges but It tried giving a role that was a row above it.